# Javascript Smallest Multiple Keeps Crashing

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

I am currently going through project euler trying to get better at javascript. I am stuck on one problem that i can't seem to figure out.

The question is:

2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder. What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

So I searched stack and found a few similar topics when i got stuck but everyones code seems to be a bit more complex than what I came up with. My problem is i was able to create the correct program to find the smallest multiple from 1-10 which i was able to get 2520 with.

However, when i adjust my program to work for numbers 1-20 it crashes. I can get 1-19 but once i do 20 i keep crashing. Here is my code. If you change it to `count != 10` and `i <= 10` you can get the answer 2520 but 20 just doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
    var num = 0;
    var count = 0;

    while (count != 20) {
        num++;
        count = 0;

        for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(num);
    console.log(count);
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"?  What exactly to you observe? What exactly happens?  A specific error message on a specific line of code?  An infinite loop?  What do you see in the debug console?   Looking at this information and reporting it as part of your problem report is the first step in debugging a problem.

Comment: To be more precise this message comes up

Error: Script terminated by timeout at:
@file:///C:/Users/Chad/Desktop/javascript%20exercises/smallestmultiple.html:25:1

Comment: That sounds like the system detected a script that was running too long and shut it down.

Comment: Yeah, that was my guess..After a few seconds my browser freezes and asks me if I want to stop running the script which makes the browser usable again.

Comment: Yep, your script is either in an infinite loop or just running far, far too long and the system is detecting that.  You will need to either diagnose the infinite loop or find a different algorithm that executes faster.  Next time, please include all this extra debugging information and observations in the original question to show us what you've done to understand the problem and to give us those important clues.

Comment: Ok, I feel like it may be the latter because it works for all numbers less than 20..maybe once it gets to 20 it just is too much to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't crash, just takes long time, since your script is inefficient.

```
<script>
    var num = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var numbers=20;

    while (count != numbers) {
        num+=numbers;
        count = 0;

        for (var i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                count++;
            }
            else {break;}
        }
    }

    console.log(num);
    console.log(count);
</script>
```

Comment: Would you mind shedding some light on what I should do that would be more efficient.

Comment: well at least you could increase num by 20, not by 1

Comment: Well, what if increasing by 20 ends up skipping over the least common multiple that i am looking for?

Comment: What is `exit;` in your script?

Comment: it cant skip, since it must be 20 multiple

Comment: I don't recognize `exit;` as a legal Javascript keyword.  That's what I'm asking.

Comment: FYI, yours take ~2x as long as mine to complete.   ;)

Comment: it takes 1 sec or so if numbers = 20, and u can make it much more efficient still. http://jsfiddle.net/2j1g200g/30/

Comment: Took over 60 when I copied and pasted it into Firebug . . . where were you running it?

Comment: You got slow PC i guess, your code runs in 0.117 seconds here

Comment: Looks like it's FireBug that's the issue (not surprising, really) . . . I ran mine in JSFiddle as well and it completed in 0.166 seconds. LOL

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, not breaking, just taking a REALLY long time. This should be a much more efficient approach:

```
var num = 1;
var isDivisible = false;
var startTime = (new Date().getTime());

while (!isDivisible) {
    for (var i = 20; i > 1; i--) {
        if (num % i !== 0) {
            isDivisible = false;
            num = num + (i + 1);
            break;
        }
        else {
            isDivisible = true;
        }
    } 
}

console.log(num);
console.log("Finished in " + (((new Date().getTime()) - startTime) / 1000) + " seconds");
```

Results:

```
232792560
Finished in 0.166 seconds
```

**Note:** above results from JSFiddle . . . finished in 26.57 seconds in Firebug.   :)